# I would like to Parallelize my Clojure implementation

Tags: clojure, future

Ok so i have an algorithm what it does is , it loops through a fill line by line and then looks for a given word in the line. Not only does it return the given word but it also returns a number(given also as a parameter) of words that come before and after that word.

```
Eg.line = "I am overflowing with blessings and you also are"
           parameters = ("you" 2)
           output = (blessings and you also are)

(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader "resources/small.txt")]
  (doseq [l (line-seq r)]
    (let [x (topMostLoop l "good" 2)]
      (if (not (empty? x))
        (println x)))))
```

the above code is working fine. But i would like to parallelize it so i did this below

```
(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader "resources/small.txt")]
  (doseq [l (line-seq r)]
    (future
      (let [x (topMostLoop l "good" 2)]
        (if (not (empty? x))
          (println x))))))
```

but then the outputs comes out all messy. I know I need to lock somewhere but dont know where.

```
(defn topMostLoop [contents word next]
  (let [mywords (str/split contents #"[ ,\\.]+")]
    (map (fn [element] (
                        return-lines (max 0 (- element next))
                        (min (+ element next) (- (count mywords) 1)) mywords))
         (vec ((indexHashMap mywords) word)))))
```

Please would be glad if someone can help me this is the last thing Im left with.

NB. Do let me know if i need to post the other functions as well

I have added the other functions for more clarity

```
(defn return-lines [firstItem lastItem contentArray]
  (take (+ (- lastItem firstItem) 1) 
        (map (fn [element] (str element))
             (vec (drop firstItem contentArray)))))

(defn indexHashMap [mywords]
  (->> (zipmap (range) mywords)     ;contents is a list of words
       (reduce (fn [index [location word]]
                 (merge-with concat index {word (list location)})) {})))
```

Comment: `I know I need to lock somewhere`, uhm no ? - try processing it in futures, an then print the result, instead of printing in futures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `map` for first example when you are using serial approach:

```
(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader "resources/small.txt")]
  (doseq [l (map #(topMostLoop %1 "good" 2) (line-seq r))]
    (if (not (empty? l))
        (println l))))
```

With this approach `topMostLoop` function is applied on each line, and lazy seq of results is returned. In body of `doseq` function results are printed if not empty.

After that, replace `map` with `pmap`, which will run mapping in parallel, and results will appear in same order as given lines:

```
(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader "resources/small.txt")]
  (doseq [l (pmap #(topMostLoop %1 "good" 2) (line-seq r))]
    (if (not (empty? l))
        (println l))))
```

In your case with futures, results will be normaly out of order (some later futures will finish execution sooner than former futures).

I tested this with following modifications (not reading text file, but creating lazy sequence of vector of numbers, searching for value in vectors and returning surrounding):

```
(def lines (repeatedly #(shuffle (range 1 11))))
(def lines-10 (take 10 lines))

lines-10
([5 8 3 10 6 9 7 2 1 4]
[6 8 9 7 2 5 10 4 1 3]
[2 7 8 9 1 5 10 3 4 6]
[10 8 3 5 7 2 4 9 6 1]
[8 6 10 1 9 4 3 7 2 5]
[9 6 8 1 5 10 3 4 2 7]
[10 9 3 7 1 8 4 6 5 2]
[6 1 4 10 3 7 8 9 5 2]
[9 6 7 5 8 3 10 4 2 1]
[4 1 5 2 7 3 6 9 8 10])

(defn surrounding
 [v value size]
  (let [i (.indexOf v value)]
   (if (= i -1)
    nil
    (subvec v (max (- i size) 0) (inc (min (+ i size) (dec (count v))))))))

(doseq [l (map #(surrounding % 3 2) lines-10)] (if (not (empty? l)) (println l)))
[5 8 3 10 6]
[4 1 3]
[5 10 3 4 6]
[10 8 3 5 7]
[9 4 3 7 2]
[5 10 3 4 2]
[10 9 3 7 1]
[4 10 3 7 8]
[5 8 3 10 4]
[2 7 3 6 9]
nil

(doseq [l (pmap #(surrounding % 3 2) lines-10)] (if (not (empty? l)) (println l)))
[5 8 3 10 6]
[4 1 3]
[5 10 3 4 6]
[10 8 3 5 7]
[9 4 3 7 2]
[5 10 3 4 2]
[10 9 3 7 1]
[4 10 3 7 8]
[5 8 3 10 4]
[2 7 3 6 9]
nil
```

Comment: it seems to be working but wanted to ask what is the purpose of the %1 in the codes. #(topMostLoop %1 "good" 2). Well the # and also %1. Pardon me , I am new to clojure

Comment: Welcome to Clojure! Map is function which in its simplest form takes two parameters: function of one argument and a collection. It traverses collection and applies passed function to each element, returning collection of results.  Your function, topMostLoop cannot be passed directly to map as it takes three arguments. Syntax #(body) creates anonymous function and ℅1 refers to first argument. So, we wrapped your function of three arguments with anonymous fn of one argument which can be passed to map. We could also write anonymous fn this way: (fn [line] (topMostLoop line "good" 2))